# установка второй операционной системы

Tags: windows

Сильно ли повлияет на производительность установка Linux, с сохранением windows 10. Компьютер не производительный, иногда лагает

Comment: нет. Не должна повлиять.  Главное, что бы на диске было достаточно места.

Answer (score 1):

Никак не повлияет. С точки зрения каждой из операционок, вторая - это просто занятое место на диске.

Answer (score 0):

У меня так и есть, стояла 10 винда, сверху установил линукс минт, на производительность никак не повлияло, просто файлы винды остались лежать в своей папке